Can't log in in django adminstrator interface with my custom backend
I've replaced default backend system with my custom one
#overriding authentication method to use email instead of an username.
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email = None, password = None):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None

and edited settings.py according to the docs
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["accounts.backends.EmailBackend"]

User model itself
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)

The problem is that I can login with the email in my html login form, but can't do the same thing in django admin interface.
What I've tried so far:

Deleted migrations folder with the database itself and then making migrations and migration
Restarting the server
Creating new superuser


Does this answer your question? Custom authentication backend. Django

So i figured out i just needed to add a kwargs argument so the function would accept additional arguments.
corrected version of the code looks like this:
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

